# Inserting Timestamp Into Snowflake Using Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an empty table defined in snowflake as;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE db1.schema1.table(
ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
PREDICTED_PROBABILITY FLOAT,
TIME_PREDICTED TIMESTAMP
);
```

And it creates the correct table, which has been checked using `desc` command in sql. Then using a snowflake python connector we are trying to execute following query;

```
insert_query =  f'INSERT INTO DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES(ACCOUNT_ID, PREDICTED_PROBABILITY, TIME_PREDICTED) VALUES ({accountId}, {risk_score},{ct});'
ctx.cursor().execute(insert_query)
```

Just before this query the variables are defined, The main challenge is getting the current time stamp written into snowflake. Here the value of `ct` is defined as;

```
import datetime
ct = datetime.datetime.now()
print(ct)
```

```
2021-04-30 21:54:41.676406
```

But when we try to execute this `INSERT` query we get the following errr message;

```
ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 157 unexpected '21'.
```

Can I kindly get some help on ow to format the date time value here? Help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe timestamp should be passed with quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer @Lukasz provided you could also think about defining the current_timestamp() as default for the TIME_PREDICTED column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE db1.schema1.table(
ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
PREDICTED_PROBABILITY FLOAT,
TIME_PREDICTED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current_timestamp
);
```

And then just insert ACCOUNT_ID and PREDICTED_PROBABILITY:

```
insert_query =  f'INSERT INTO DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES(ACCOUNT_ID, PREDICTED_PROBABILITY) VALUES ({accountId}, {risk_score});'
ctx.cursor().execute(insert_query)
```

It will automatically assign the insert time to TIME_PREDICTED

Answer (score 0):

Educated guess. When performing insert with:

```
insert_query =  f'INSERT INTO ...(ACCOUNT_ID, PREDICTED_PROBABILITY, TIME_PREDICTED) 
VALUES ({accountId}, {risk_score},{ct});'
```

It is a string interpolation. The `ct` is provided as string representation of datetime, which does not match a timestamp data type, thus error.

I would suggest using proper [variable binding](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#qmark-or-numeric-binding) instead:

```
ctx.cursor().execute("INSERT INTO DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES "
                     "(ACCOUNT_ID, PREDICTED_PROBABILITY, TIME_PREDICTED) "
                     "VALUES(:1, :2, :3)",
                      (accountId,
                       risk_score, 
                       ("TIMESTAMP_LTZ", ct) 
                      )
                   );
```

---

> [Avoid SQL Injection Attacks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#avoid-sql-injection-attacks)
>
> **Avoid binding data using Python’s formatting function because you risk SQL injection.** For example:
>
> ```
> # Binding data (UNSAFE EXAMPLE)
> con.cursor().execute(
>     "INSERT INTO testtable(col1, col2) "
>     "VALUES({col1}, '{col2}')".format(
>         col1=789,
>         col2='test string3')
>     )
> ```
>
> Instead, store the values in variables, check those values (for example, by looking for suspicious semicolons inside strings), and then bind the parameters using qmark or numeric binding style.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to place the quotes before and after the {ct}. The code should be :

```
insert_query =  "INSERT INTO DATA_LAKE.CUSTOMER.ACT_PREDICTED_PROBABILITIES(ACCOUNT_ID, PREDICTED_PROBABILITY, TIME_PREDICTED) VALUES ({accountId}, {risk_score},'{ct}');".format(accountId=accountId,risk_score=risk_score,ct=ct)
ctx.cursor().execute(insert_query)
```